# How to hide/show a button with another button | Flutter?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

New to programming and dart/flutter .

Thank You.

So 2 buttons Me! and You! , I have to hide and show me! button clicking on You! button .
So can any one help me to find solution of my question.

and what if i have more numbers of buttons and show/hide all of them using a single button.

My code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Me!'),
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('You!'),
              color: Colors.red,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can show/hide any widget based on a bool variable, and set the value of bool to true/false using setState in ontap on any button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 3 examples.

## 1

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool hide = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            if(!hide)MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Me!'),
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                 setState((){
                    hide = !hide;
                 });
              },
              child: Text('${hide ? "Show" : "Hide"}'),
              color: Colors.red,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## 2

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool hide = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Opacity(
              opacity: hide ? 0 : 1,
              child: MaterialButton(
                 onPressed: () {},
                 child: Text('Me!'),
                 color: Colors.green,
             )
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                 setState((){
                    hide = !hide;
                 });
              },
              child: Text('${hide ? "Show" : "Hide"}'),
              color: Colors.red,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## 3 (Adding animation)

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool hide = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            AnimatedOpacity(
              opacity: hide ? 0 : 1,
              duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
              child: MaterialButton(
                 onPressed: () {},
                 child: Text('Me!'),
                 color: Colors.green,
             )
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                 setState((){
                    hide = !hide;
                 });
              },
              child: Text('${hide ? "Show" : "Hide"}'),
              color: Colors.red,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note: The first example will remove the button from the widget tree. For the second and third, the button will be in the widget tree but won't be visible.

So you can see it as:
First example: The button is GONE.
Second example: The button is INVISIBLE.

Answer (score 3):

use a Visibility Widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isVisible = true; //will be visible for the first frame
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Visibility(
              visible: isVisible,
              child: MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text('Me!'),
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isVisible = !isVisible;
                });
              },
              child: Text('You!'),
              color: Colors.red,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```